# Enable/Disable a button if check boxes are checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes in a table and I have written the code for selecting/deselecting all checkboxes and enabling/disabling a button with it. (Select All Checkbox is the header of the column)

```
$(function(){
   $('#SelectAll').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;                        
        });
        $('#Assign').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    if(!this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
       });
       $('#Assign').attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
});
});
```

Although if a user decides to check the checkboxes individually and uncheckes all in he process how do I write the below code to check if all of them are unchecked and disable the button

```
 $(function(){
$(':checkbox').click(function(event){
    if(this.checked){
        $('#Assign').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    if(!this.checked){
        //Need to put code here to check if all of them are unchecked
           {
                 //disable the Assign button if all are unchecked by user
                 $('#Assign').attr("disabled","disabled");
               }

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The overall function can be simplified as

```
$(function(){
    var checkboxes = $(':checkbox:not(#SelectAll)').click(function(event){
        $('#Assign').prop("disabled", checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == 0);
    });

    $('#SelectAll').click(function(event) {   
        checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
        $('#Assign').prop("disabled", !this.checked)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BqEyg/)

Comment: How to apply this function for dynamically created check box ? 
On page load, There will be 5 check box. After clicking 'Load More' I'm adding 5 more check boxes. The above function is not selecting the dynamic check boxes. I'm using jQuery v2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

My own take on this, despite your having already accepted an answer, would be the following:

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.prop('disabled', function(i,d) {
        return !d;
    }).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);
});
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var all = $(this).closest('tbody').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $('#selectAll').prop('disabled',function(){
        return all.length === all.filter(':checked').length;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/phFFv/2/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery function `.attr("checked", true/false)` and `.removeAttr("checked")` works not good. Better use `.click()` function. You can see it in `Opera 12.16` on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/KG67W/3/) link if you comment `6` and `9` javascript strings and uncomment `7` and `11`. `Select all` and `Deselect all` buttons works only first time with uncommented strings.
HTML:

```
<table><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Select all:</td>
        <td><button onclick="chk(this, true);">Select all</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Deselect all:</td>
        <td><button onclick="chk(this, false);">Deselect all</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First checkbox:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="chk(this, null);" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second checkbox:</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="chk(this, null);" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enabled/disabled button:</td>
        <td><button id="enDisButton" disabled="disabled">If you can click on me then I'm enabled</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Javascript:

```
function chk(elem, selectAll){
    // input/button -> td -> tr -> tbody
    var tbody = $($(elem).parent().parent().parent());
    console.log("cb");
    if (selectAll === true) {
        tbody.find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').click();
        //tbody.find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr("checked", true);
    } else if (selectAll === false) {
        tbody.find('input:checkbox:checked').click();
        //tbody.find('input:checkbox:checked').attr("checked", false);
    } else {
        //clicking on checkbox
    }
    // all unchecked
    if (tbody.find('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
        $("#enDisButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    // all checked
    } else if (tbody.find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0) {
        $("#enDisButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```